# Show that the order of an element g is well-defined

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and let $g∈G$, explain why the order of $g$ is well-defined, while the definition of the order is the following:

The smallest positive r such that $g^r=e$, if no such r is found then we say g has infinite order.

**My Question**:
What strategy should I adopt to check the well-definedness? I know we are essentially checking if the output is unique or not.

**My Attempt**: Suppose the order of g is finite then consider the set $\{r>0:g^r=e\}$. We know this set is non-empty since $g^k=e$ for some $k$. Then by Well-Ordering Principle there exists smallest such $r$ and hence the order is well-defined.

Comment: Which definition of the order of an element do you have?

Comment: "Well-defined" is usually used when there is a choice to be made. For example, when working with cosets the representatives represent a "choice". A question might be "prove that the order of an element of $G/N$ is well defined", and you prove that if $gN=hN$ and if $g^n\in N$ then $h^n\in N$. So, at least to me, this question makes no sense in its current form.

Comment: Usually the order of an element $g$ is defined as smallest positive integer $r$ with $g^r=e$ together with the clausule that $g$ has infinite order if no such integer exists. A check on well-definedness is not justified, since no choice is made. It is as if you are asked to prove that $\mathbb N$ is well-ordered.

Comment: @Bernard The definition given to me was the smallest positive integer r such that $g^r=e$, if no such r qualifies then we say g has infinite order.

Comment: The smallest positive integer in a set of positive integers always exists, so why bother?

Comment: @Bernard Wait, is it the case that I need to check if such function cannot assign two values at once? As in, Suppose the orders of g are $m$, $n$ respectively then $m-n$ qualifies for such definition, too? I really have no idea  what I am checking to be fair.

Comment: If $m-n>0$, this means $m$ was not the smallest positive integer such that … Again, the *smallest positive integer* in a set of positive integers is unique, as the order on $\mathbf N$ is a total order..

Comment: I've realised where the choice is made. The choice is picking two $m, n$ minimal such that $g^n=1=g^m$. This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is good, but not correct. You cannt say “Suppose the order of $g$ is finite”, since this already *assumes* that the order exists. You can consider two cases:

1. $(\forall k\in\mathbb N):g^k\neq e$: then, by definition, $\operatorname{ord}f=\infty$.
2. $g^k=e$ for some natural $k$. Then, by the Well-Ordering Principle, there is a smallest such $k$, in which case $\operatorname{ord}g=k$.

Comment: It would be nice if you could address the comments to the question, which are asking *why* well-definedness is necessary here. So far as I understand it, it is not necessary and the question makes no sense...

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the spirit of the comments. Yes, it is easy to prove what the OP tried to prove just by mentioning the Well-Ordering Principle. Which the OP did, by the way. If all the rest was fine, I would not have answered; I would have just posted a comment saying that the proof was fine. But it was not fine and there *was* something to be proved, no matter how easy the proof is.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.